# High Charts Breaking jQuery Across Rails App

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, highcharts

I have the following code in my static_pages.js.coffee file and it works great, except when loading any other page on my site, this code runs and looks for .orders-chart.  High Charts throws an error and breaks all my other jQuery if I don't have that div on the page.

```
jQuery ->
$ ->
  new Highcharts.Chart
    chart: 
      renderTo: "orders-chart"
    title:
      text: "Orders by Day"
    xAxis:
      type: "datetime"
    yAxis:
      title:
        text: "Some Measurable"
    series: [
      pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
      data: [1, 2, 3, 5, 7]
    ]
```

is there a way to check for .orders-chart before running this code?  Or a better way of doing things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think highChart looks for `#orders-chart` and not `.orders-chart`
So you need to have

```
 <div id="orders-chart" ></div>
```

And not

```
 <div class="orders-chart" ></div>
```

To check if it exists or not, you can use

```
if ($("#orders-chart").length>0) {
   // Call chart constructor here
}
```

fiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/bD487/

Comment: Everything works with ids and I have a number of charts... it is best practice to give each one a separate class?

Comment: each one needs to have a separate id, classes can repeat

Comment: Yup, this worked.  I stuck with the ID since I have a bunch of charts with different info.  The only think I left out when trying the other answer was the `> 0`. User error I guess, but since you have it here, I accepted this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to write this for your Ruby implementation, but in plain jQuery code, to check for the existence of an element you can use length:

```js
if ($(".orders-chart").length) {
    // .orders-chart exists, do stuff...
}
```

Comment: I've seen this before and tried it, but I couldn't get it to work.  Not sure if I'm just not implementing it correctly with coffeScript or what.